# How can I prevent any window from minimizing?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, dwm

I am setting up a kiosk/POS computer that runs certain applications from a launcher. I've got everything set up the way I need except for one thing.

I am able to close the launched applications (like Chrome or IE, for example), but I don't want to be able to minimize them because the taskbar is disabled.

How can I go about either completely disabling minimization (or a similar workaround to achieve the above goal)?

---

Edit: One potential solution I tried was to loop this Powershell script every few seconds or so:

```
$dllInfo = '[DllImport("user32.dll")] public static extern bool ShowWindowAsync(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);'
Add-Type -MemberDefinition $dllInfo -name NativeMethods -namespace Win32
foreach($proc in Get-Process){
    $hwnd = $proc.MainWindowHandle
    # Restore window
    [Win32.NativeMethods]::ShowWindowAsync($hwnd, 4) | Out-Null
}
```

But that just resulted in my processor being bogged down to an usuable state. Any other ideas or improvements on this one?

Comment: I don't know the details, but my guess is you have a LOT of processes running, and only a few have windows. So, you could cache that list and filter out those that won't have windows (e.g. those that are already running when you start your kiosk). Or, a second after you launch an app, grab its process ID and then watch it.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Actually, there aren't too many. Windows is essentially locked down to no taskbar and Rainmeter is running as the end user UI. Rainmeter can launch a couple websites in either chrome or IE, and that's about it. At idle, these are my usage stats: https://i.imgur.com/038BmGd.png

Comment: But, how many processes does Get-Process return, and how many could you filter it down to?

Comment: @DanielGriscom Ah, yes. I didn't think about that. I suppose that's a rather crude way of doing it, I'm not as good with powershell :/

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of Windows products that support feature-limiting for kiosks. Auto-restarting, blocking the task bar, window control, preventing use of Explorer, blocking special keystrokes, etc. I've used SiteKiosk in the past, but it's been a while, so I don't know whether it's been surpassed since then.

Some possibly useful links:

- http://www.capterra.com/kiosk-software/
- https://webconverger.org/blog/entry/SiteKiosk_versus_Webconverger/

Comment: I've already settled on a kiosk software, thanks! It's more or less a custom designed shell. It was just this one problem that I needed to conquer via scripting or some other means.